# How can an ActiveRecord::Relation object call class methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How can an ActiveRecord::Relation object call class methods?

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project

  def self.initial_tasks # class methods
   # here return initial tasks
  end
end
```

Now we can call :

```
Project.first.tasks.initial_tasks # how it works
```

`initial_tasks` is a class method and we can't call class methods on an object.

`Project.first.tasks` returns an ActiveRecord::Relation object, so how could it be able to  call `initial_tasks`?

Please explain.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Your method's name is self.initial_task*s*, but you're calling .initial_task? Which one is right?

Comment: sorry its "initial_tasks".

Comment: Any luck with this so far?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There's not much documentation on the application on class methods to `ActiveRecord::Relation` objects, but we can understand this behavior by taking a look at how [ActiveRecord scopes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html) work.

First, a Rails model scope will return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. From the docs:

> Class methods on your model are automatically available on scopes. Assuming the following setup:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :published, -> { where(published: true) }
  scope :featured, -> { where(featured: true) }

  def self.latest_article
    order('published_at desc').first
  end

  def self.titles
    pluck(:title)
  end
end
```

First, invoking a scope returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object:

```
Article.published.class
#=> ActiveRecord::Relation

Article.featured.class
#=> ActiveRecord::Relation
```

Then, you can operate on the `ActiveRecord::Relation` object using the respective model's class methods:

```
Article.published.featured.latest_article
Article.featured.titles
```

It's a bit of a roundabout way of understanding the relationship between class methods and `ActiveRecord::Relation`, but the gist is this:

1. *By definition*, model scopes return `ActiveRecord::Relation` objects
2. *By definition*, scopes have access to class methods
3. ***Therefore***, `ActiveRecord::Relation` objects have access to class methods

Comment: Hey friend this saves my day !!

Answer (score 31):

It's extremely easy to explore. You just do so:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project

  def self.initial_tasks  #class methods
    1 / 0
  end
end
```

Then call `Project.first.tasks.initial_tasks` and you get:

```
  Division by zero
  ...
  .../gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:70:in `block in re
  .../gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:872:in `
  .../gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:286:in `scoping'",
  .../gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:872:in `
  .../gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:70:in `initial_tasks'",
```

And that's all you need basically. Easy to explore but not so easy to understand.

Now I'll explain what that means.
When you call `Project#tasks` method it *does not* return you ActiveRecord::Relation object. Actually it returns you an instance of runtime-created class named Task::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy inherited from ActiveRecord::Associations::CollextionProxy that in turn inherited from ActiveRecord::Relation. This runtime-created class is linked with Task class and contains dynamically-defined (via method_missing)  proxy-methods that delegate calls to Task class methods and merge association scope with class-defined scope returned by class-level methods.

How it works (really non-trivial):

1. There is ActiveRecord::Base class. Class object extended by
   [ActiveRecord::Delegation::DelegateCache](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb#L7) module [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L282).
2. DelegateCache has `DelegateCache.inherited` callback that defines `@relation_delegate_cache` attribute every time you inherit ActiveRecord::Base. It means all AR::Base descendant classes will have such attribute. The callback [calls](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb#L12) `DelegateCache#initialize_relation_delegate_cache` method which in order fills cache attribute with runtime-created classes:

   ```
   [
     ActiveRecord::Relation,
     ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy,
     ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation
   ].each do |klass|
     delegate = Class.new(klass) {
       include ClassSpecificRelation
     }
     const_set klass.name.gsub('::', '_'), delegate
     cache[klass] = delegate
   end
   ```

   Here these classes get unusual names a-la `Task::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy` 
   mentioned earlier.
3. Ok, now our Task model has links to runtime-defined relation classes. These classes have some concern called ClassSpecificRelation (included [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb#L20)). The concern adds method_missing method that detects your class-method calls on a relation object (for instance calling `#initial_tasks` on `Project.tasks`). On such call it [dynamically defines](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb#L63) new runtime-class instance methods that delegate to class-level methods. Now you have Task class linked to Task::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy class containing all instance-level methods that proxy calls to Task class-level methods get scope result and merge it with current association scope ([here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb#L70)).

That's how AR prefers dynamically-defined methods on runtime-created classes over using inefficient method_missing calls on ActiveRecord::Relation.

I think it's OK if you do not understand all this stuff. Just call class-level methods on associations :)

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to understand all the concepts. Will comment again if some doubts appear. As a first comment I think you are probably talking about activerecord-4.x.x so I think that's the reason why the class of the result of calling `Project#task` is not an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. Moreover, the class methods of an ActiveRecord model are not only available to corresponding associations but also to his own relations or scopes. But I think that the way of "having access" of these methods is the same you described above :) Thanks, will update soon.

Comment: @flyer88 Yes, Rails 3.2 just uses method_missing on ActiveRecord::Relation https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb#L34. Also CollectionProxy is not ActiveRecord::Relation subclass https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb#L36. So things were simpler in 3.2.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone struggling to actually access a filtered list of records inside a class method you can simply call `all` which will return you the list you are expecting rather than all of the records in that table which is accessed with `relation`.

Answer (score 0):

Here in ActiveRecord::Relation, Relation is representing whole table 
and your class Post is map with table,

So ActiveRecord::Relation is array or single record it can access class method.