# Best code structure for Rails associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

#### The Stage

Lets talk about the most common type of association we encounter.

I have a User which `:has_many` Post(s)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

#### Problem Statement

I want to do some (very light and quick) processing on all the posts of a user. I am looking for the best way to structure my code to achieve it. Below are a couple of ways and why they work or don't work.

#### Method 1

Do it in the `User` class itself.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts

  def process_posts
    posts.each do |post|
      # code of whatever 'process' does to posts of this user
    end
  end
end
```

Post class remains the same:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The method is called as:

```
User.find(1).process_posts
```

**Why doesn't this look the best way to do it**

The logic of doing something with the posts of the user should really belong to the Post class. In a real world scenario, a user might also have `:has_many` relations with a lot of other classes e.g. `orders`, `comments`, `children` etc.

If we start adding similar `process_orders`, `process_comments`, `process_children` (yikes) methods to the User class, it'll result in one giant file with lots of code much of which could (and should) be distributed to where it belongs i.e. the target associations.

#### Method 2

Proxy Associations and Scopes

Both of these constructs require addition of methods/code to the User class which again makes it bloated. I'd rather have **all** implementation shifted to the target classes.

#### Method 3

Class Method on target Class

Create class methods in the target class and call those methods on the User object.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  # all target specific code in target classes
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  # Class method
  def self.process
    Post.all.each do |post|  # see Note 2 below
      # code of whatever 'process' does to posts of this user
    end
  end
end
```

The method is called as:

```
User.find(1).posts.process   # See Note 1 below
```

Now, this looks and feels better than Method 1 and 2 because:

- User model remains clutter free.
- The process function is called `process` instead of `process_posts`. Now we can have a `process` for other classes as well and invoke them as: `User.find(1).orders.process` etc. instead of `User.find(1).process_orders` (Method 1).

**Note 1:**

Yes you can call a class method like this on a association. [Read why here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21681107/how-activerecordrelation-object-can-call-class-methods). TL;DR is that `User.find(1).posts` returns a CollectionProxy object which has access to class methods of the target (Post) class. It also conveniently passes a `scope_attributes` which stores the user_id of the user which called `posts.process`. This comes handy. See Note 2 below.

**Note 2:**

For people not sure whats going on when we do a `Post.all.each` in the class method, it returns all the posts of the **user this method was called on** as against all the posts in the database.

So when called as `User.find(99).posts.process`, `Post.all` executes:

```
SELECT "notes".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 99]]
```

which are all the posts for User ID: 99.

Per @Jesuspc's comment below, `Post.all.each` can be succinctly written as `all.each`. Its more idiomatic and doesn't make it look like we are querying all posts in the database.

#### The Answer I am looking for

- Explains what is the best way to handle such associations. How do people do it normally? and if there are any obvious design flaws in Method 3.

Comment: By the way, your self.process method from the third option may be more idiomatic if instead of Post.all your simply use all. Post.all is confusing because it looks like you are querying all the posts (global scope) when in fact what is happening is that it queries for all elements in the given scope.

Comment: @Jesuspc, good point. I've added the note in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a fourth option. Move this logic out of the model entirely:

```
class PostProcessor
  def initialize(posts)
    @posts = posts
  end

  def process
    @posts.each do |post|
      # ...
    end
  end
end

PostProcessor.new(User.find(1).posts).process
```

This is sometimes called the Service Object pattern. A very nice bonus of this approach is that it makes writing tests for this logic really simple. Here's a great blog post on this and other ways to refactor "fat" models: http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

Comment: +1 I agree. I mentioned `(very light and quick) processing` in the question to indicate that maybe the few lines of code might not warrant a new class altogether. Nevertheless, good that you pointed out the Fourth method.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think that **Method 1** is the cleanest one. It will be very clean and understandable write something like this:

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts

  def process_posts
    posts.each do |post|
     post.process
    end
  end
end
```

And put all the logic of `process` method in `Post` model (with an instance variable):

```
Class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def process
     # Logic of your Post process
  end
end
```

That way, the very logic of a `Post` process belong to `Post` class. Even if your `User` model will have many "process" functions, these will be very basic and small. That seems very clean to me, as a developer.

**Method 3** has many technical implications that are pretty complex and unintuitive (yourself had to clarify your question).

NOTE: If you want better performance, maybe you should use `eager loading` to reduce `ActiveRecord` calls, but that is out of the scope of this question.

Comment: As the user of the 'language', you don't have to deal with the complexities of Method 3. Under the hood, there are many complex things going on in the code that you posted. So far as you are dealing with abstractions, and you have a clean interface to work with, the underlying framework complexities should not be a deterrent in your decision to use one technique over the other. The things that I (had to) explain have been implemented in the framework just so that we can use the niceties it brings to us as Rails programmers.

Comment: @NayaBonbo In my (humble) point of view, the underlying framework complexities SHOULD be a deterrent in your decision. I write code so that other developers can read and familiarize quickly. Using niceties in my code does not help matters.

Comment: But doesn't that mean one can't use advanced framework or language features just because it makes the code difficult to understand for other developers who don't know the language as much as you do?
I get what you are trying to say though. I guess moderation is the key and probably one shouldn't use arcane features which are beyond the understanding of 90% developers.

Answer (score 1):

First of all excuse me for the opinionated answer.

ActiveRecord models are a controversial matter. Its essence is against the *Single responsibility principle* since they handle both database interaction via class methods and domain objects (which use to implement their own behaviour) via its instances. At the same time they also break the *Liskov Substitution Principle* because the models are not sub cases of ActiveRecord::Base and implement their own set of methods. And finally the ActiveRecord paradigm often leads to code that breaks the *Law of Demeter*, as in your proposal for the third method:

```
User.find(1).posts.process
```

Thus, there is a trend that in order to reduce coupling would recommend to use ActiveRecord objects only to interact with the database and therefore no behaviour should be added to them (in your case the **process** method). Under my point of view that is the lesser evil, even though it is still not a perfect solution.

So if I were to implement what you describe I would have a ProcessablePostsCollection object (where the name Processable can be customised to better describe what the processing is about, or even neglected completely so you would simple have a PostsCollection class) that would probably be a wrapper over a list of posts using SimpleDelegator and would have a method **process**.

```
class ProcessablePostsCollection < SimpleDelegator
  def self.from_collection(collection)
    new collection
  end

  def initialize(source)
    super source
  end

  def process
    # code of whatever 'process' does to posts
  end
end
```

And the usage would be something like:

```
ProcessablePostsCollection.from_collection(User.find(1).posts).process
```

even though the **from_collection** and the call to **process** should happen in different clases.

Also, in case you have a big posts table it would probably be wise to process stuff in batches. For that your **process** method could call **find_in_batches** on your posts ActiveRecord::Relation.

But as always it depends on your needs. If you are simply building a prototype is perfectly fine to let your models grow fat, and if you are building an enormous application Rails itself is probably not going to be the best choice since discourages some OOP best practises with things such as ActiveRecord models.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your overview. I sure got illuminated today with the _Single responsibility principle_ and the _lay of demeter_ ;)
Your answer jives well with what Jordan wrote. A separate class makes sense depending on the business logic of what the `process` method does.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be putting this in the `User` model - put it in `Post` (unless - of course - the scope of `process` involves the `User` model directly) :

```
#app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    def process
       return false if post.published?
       # do something
    end
end
```

Then you can use an ActiveRecord Association Extension to add the functionality to the `User` model:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :posts do
      def process
          proxy_association.target.each do |post|
             post.process
          end
      end
   end
end
```

This will allow you to call...

```
@user = User.find 1
@user.posts.process
```

Comment: +1 This is the 'Rails way' of extending the functionality of the association. Thanks for showing the exact code to do it. This will be helpful for people who want stick to the prescribed way for doing such a thing in Rails. My concern in using extensions is that the user class will get cluttered with the logic of various disparate classes (in case we need to have extensions for many associated classes). For a one off extension which has a few lines of implementation, this totally works.
Interestingly the calling syntax in this method is same as what I have in Method 3 - `@user.posts.process`.