# ActiveRecord Relation scoped access associated belongs_to object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am wondering if there is a way to access the associated belongs_to Object in a ActiveRecord::Relation

For example in this relation:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoices
end


class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer

  def self.check_new
    # do something
  rescue => e
    MyLogger.log_error_for(customer, __method__)
  end
end
```

So if I call

```
Customer.first.invoices.check_new
```

and an error occurs. I want to log this error for this particular customer.

I know I can get the invoices with `scoped` inside the class method and call `scoped.first.customer`.
But this seems a little dirty. Also if there arent any invoices yet, this wont be a solution.

I am not shure if there is a ways to do that but an inspect on scoped gives you something like:

```
SELECT * FROM SOME JOIN WHERE customer_id = 1
```

So there is kind a reference to the Customer object.
Can anyone help?

UPDATE:
This is just an example. Actually I do not do logging or something. Of course they are better ways to do logging. 
All I want is to place code of updating a collection inside of the model class. Like a normal Customer.first.invoices.create would do. AND have access to the parent of this relation.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly something like:

```
  customer = Customer.first
  customer.invoices.each {|invoice| invoice.check_new}
```

A couple of other thoughts:

UPDATE:

I would think that `Customer.first.invoices.check_new` would throw an error because you're trying to call an class method on a collection.

^^^

This is incorrect. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21681107/how-activerecordrelation-object-can-call-class-methods).

You may be able to do what you're asking. I don't know. It seems really convoluted. I'm sure you have a valid use case. But, it's not clear what it is. I would still likely do something like:

```
  customer = Customer.first
  customer.invoices.check_new
```

This does **not** answer your question, so apologies if it doesn't fit your use case.

END UPDATE.

So, `.check_new` should be an instance method. Something along the lines of:

```
  class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

    def check_new
      if errors = check_for_errors
        MyLogger.log_error_for(customer, __method__, errors)
      end
    end

    private 

    def check_for_errors
      ... error checking logic
    end

  end
```

To keep your models skinny, you might make a plain old Ruby object, like:

```
  #app/managers/invoice_manager.rb
  class InvoiceManager

    class << self

      def check_new(invoices)
        invoices.each do |invoice|
          @invoice = invoice
          if @errors = invoice_errors
            log_errors
          end
        end
      end

      private

      def invoice_errors
        ... invoice error checking logic
      end

      def log_errors
        MyLogger.log_error_for(invoice.customer, caller[0][/`.*'/][1..-2], @errors)
      end

    end 

  end
```

In which case, you would do something like:

```
  InvoiceManager.check_new(Customer.first.invoices)
```

That way, your `Invoice` model is back to handling just database interactions and your business logic is cleanly separated.

Also, using this approach, your controller doesn't need to access the `Invoice` class or instances thereof at all. Or, know anything at all about the `Invoice` class. This improves the separation between your `Controller` and `Model` layers. And makes potential, downstream changes to `Invoice` less disruptive.

Finally, I find testing POROs a lot easier than testing controllers.

Comment: This solution would solve just this specific problem (In a better way of design of corse). But it is just an example, maybe not the best, sorry for that. The topic of the post is the major question. Call a class method on a collection do not raise an error, it just calles the method.

Comment: Glad to be of some help. Good luck! And remember to 'accept' if you are so inclined. By the way, I think your example was workable - so, nice job.

Comment: Correct you are on calling class methods on ActiveRecord::Relation. I'll update my post.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I already knew the related post, unfortunately it doesnt answer my question. There is a relation in the scope to customer, how can I access this relation inside the scope.

Comment: OK. Provided one more update. I'm sure you have a valid use case. Don't know the answer. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You are a bit confused.

Here is a working example, for simplicity with controller

WhateverController

```
def show  #(no matter which one, could be index or anything with GET request)
  @user = Customer.first
  @invoice = @user.invoices.first   #works with the properly set up belongs_to and has_many associations which you did well
  @invoice.check_new  #it is called on an instance (object) of invoice class, not on the class it self as you do
end
```

class Invoice

```
 def check_new  #if you put self before the method name then it is a class method and self is equal to Invoice (class name), if you don't then it's an instance method
   self.do_something  #now self means the instance itself which is the single @invoice at the moment. If you use self within the class method then this self would mean Invoice class just like in the name of the method
 end
```

Basically you use class method when you work with the class itself and you don't try to do anything with a single instance. For example

```
@invoices = Invoice.limit(10).order(create_at: :desc)
```

Here you are trying to find bunch of the instances of the class, so you can't use a method on a single instance. But let's say you wanna modify the attributes of some instances. So you have to go to that instance and change it like:

```
@invoices.each do |invoice|
  invoice.check_new
  invoice.amount = 10
end
```

Here you change one instance at a time, so you need instance method.

I'd recommend to hit up google and check out the differences. This is pretty crucial in rails

Comment: To stay with the example: I dont want to call check_new on an instance of Invoice. I want to call them "on the/all invoices" of the customer.
I did some research on the topic, and have done  some workarounds.

Comment: What do you wanna do with the method? If you wanna deal with the attributes of 1 or more instances, then you will use instance method. For first of course you have to find the given instances with a class method. `@customer = Customer.first` is your class method in this case that you call on `Customer class`. `@invoices = @customer.invoices` is an instance method since u call it on the `@customer` instance. Then you iterate thru many `@invoices` with each, but then thanks to the iteration u will call an instance method  like `invoice.some_method`.