# What's @klass inside ActiveRecord::Delegation module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

With respect to this post: 
[How can an ActiveRecord::Relation object call class methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21681107/how-can-an-activerecordrelation-object-call-class-methods),

I was skimming through the code of the `ActiveRecord::Delegation` [module](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb) but still can't figure out what `@klass` refers to inside the nested module `ClassSpecificRelation`.

I'm suspecting it's the class name of my model (Person, Job, whatever) but can't be sure. And where does it come from?

Thanks

Comment: `@klass` should be an actual class, not just a name. `@klass` is set in a couple other classes/modules that are extended/included into `ActiveRecord::Base` so hunt around the whole directory for "klass", set some breakpoints in likely places, and step through the code in a debugger. There is a lot of action-at-a-distince in the Rails source and it is rather complex, good luck.

Comment: @muistooshort is spot on. That module is the holy grail of brain melting meta-magic.

Comment: @max Don't you mean ["ark"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YcR9k8o4I0w)? Whatever you do, don't look at it!