# How does ActiveRecord::Relation get added to Rails' models and why does each model have individual Relation class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Suppose I have a Rails model: `class Project < ActiveRecord::Base`

In the Rails console:

```
> Project.all
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

That seems reasonable. However,

```
> Project.all.class
=> Project::ActiveRecord_Relation
```

What *is* `Project::ActiveRecord_Relation`? Specifically,

- How did it get "added" (namespaced into) to my model class?
- How does it respond to `is_a?` correctly? `Project.all.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Relation)` returns `true` (which is expected), but is `Project::ActiveRecord_Relation` actually an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation`, or is it something else?
- Why do this? Why doesn't `Project.all` return an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, rather than `Project::ActiveRecord_Relation`?

(This is in the context of Rails 5.1, in case it's changed in older or newer versions.)

(I'm open to title edits if someone else can come up with a better title for this question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually two questions you are asking:

1. How does it work?
2. Why is it like that? (What for?)

`@arieljuod` has already given you some explanations and a link.

However the second question is still unanswered.

There is another similar question exists which I hope will help you find all the answers:

[How can an ActiveRecord::Relation object call class methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21681107/how-can-an-activerecordrelation-object-call-class-methods/21681483)

It looks like the two questions (by the link and yours one) answer each other )

Take a look at `@nikita-shilnikov`'s answer. Good luck in your investigation!

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! I didn't realize it was possible to use class methods as scopes, so didn't think to go down that line of exploration. It seems like being able to support that is the primary motivation behind this pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Check this line of code from ActiveRecord.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f40860800c231ecd1daef6cf6b5a8a8eda76478d/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb#L23

```
mangled_name = klass.name.gsub("::", "_")
```

So, for your questions:

- it get's added on activerecord's base when it extendes the delegation module https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f40860800c231ecd1daef6cf6b5a8a8eda76478d/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L290
- it's actually the same class, just something like an alias (not actually an alias, it's a constant with the class as value)
- the class is actually an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, it's just that the name was changed

Comment: And all the class methods from `Project` get mixed into `Project::ActiveRecord_Relation`, that's how you can say `Project.where(...).some_scope` and also why you can implement scopes as explicit class methods.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize class methods were available as scopes; seems like that's the key insight I missed here. I upvoted this answer, but I'm going to give @chumakoff the ✅ because he better addressed the "what for"