# why am i seeing User::ActiveRecord_Relation instead of ActiveRecord::Relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autoload

I'm on rails 6.0.0beta3 (with the new zeitwerk autoloader).

I'm just doing in `rails console`:

```
User.all.class # => User::ActiveRecord_Relation
```

anybody knows if this is expected behavior or maybe a zeitwerk (new autoloading gem) bug?

maybe something wrong is going on in my code (pretty simple rails app to be honest).

Comment: It is expected behaviour. Read this for more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55306333/how-does-activerecordrelation-get-added-to-rails-models-and-why-does-each-mod/55307843#55307843

Comment: thanks @chumakoff, not sure how I didn't find it, marking as duplicate